# Facetgrid Formatting and sorting each graph

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

Below is the code I've created to run the facetgrid graph. As you can see, merged1 is the first dataframe and merged2 is the second dataframe I am iterating on. There are two things I am trying to accomplish.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 5000, 200,5, 900 ], ['tom', 7000, 500,5, 900 ], ['nick', 7000,300,4 ,4000], ['nick', 8000,200,4 ,4000], ['juli',9000,300,2, 8000,], ['juli',15000,300,2, 8000,], ['TEST',10000,300,3,8000], ['TEST',8000,800,3,8000],['hang', 5000, 330,1.6,5000 ], ['hang', 1000, 330,5,5000 ]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Donor', 'Days-post-ARV','CD4', 'VL','Days Post-COLDATE'])

#creating two separate datframes
merged1=df.drop(columns=['CD4'])
merged2=df.drop(columns=['VL'])

#function for reference vertical line 
def vertical_mean_line(x, **kwargs):
    plt.axvline(x.mean(), **kwargs)  

#for the first dataframe    
g = sns.relplot(data=merged1, x='Days-post-ARV', y='VL', col='Donor',col_wrap=3, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5,
                color='b')
#for the vertical line
g.map(vertical_mean_line, 'Days Post-COLDATE',ls="--",color='g')

#for the second dataframe
for patid, ax in g.axes_dict.items():  # axes_dict is new in seaborn 0.11.2
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(data=merged2[merged2['Donor'] == patid], x='Days-post-ARV', y='CD4', color='r', ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_ylim(0,1200)

g.add_legend()   
g.tight_layout()
```

1. What's the best way to sort the graph? I'd like to switch the order of the second and third graph.
2. When plotting, the Y-axis between each graph gets merged and seeing only the 'CD4' between each graph, but there is the first Y-axis label 'VL' that should be showing up. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Note that, just like [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119258/how-to-share-facetgrid-x-and-y-axis-using-seaborn), your post is lacking reproducible test data and the necessary library imports.  Now, to set the suppressed y-labels of the main axes, you could try `ax.set_ylabel('VL')` inside the `for` loop (`for patid, ax in g.axes_dict.items(): ...`).  To set the order of the columns, you could use `sns.relplot(....., col_order=...)`.

Comment: I am working with sensitive data so i created some random numbers. Please take a look and let me know if you need anything

Comment: Hey JohanC, it was helpful but it did not give me what I needed. I had to find a quick solution so what I did was I manually set the y limit with ```ax1.set_ylim(0,1200)```

Comment: Right, thanks for your work with it, JohanC! I've accepted your answer just now

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the ```ax1.set_ylabel('VL')``` but this gets rid of other y-axis label. I need to keep both.

Comment: Are you sure about the subplots following the order list of donors appearing in the dataframe? It did not follow the order of how they appear in dataframe. I tried this and did not work

Comment: yup I tried both ```ax.set_ylabel('VL') ``` and ```ax1.set_ylabel('VL')```. The problem is that I need to keep both

Comment: Yeah, I tried the col order as well and did not work.I have a feeling that this must be coming from a data type issue.

Comment: for the formatting, I need to show both the CD4 and VL Y-axis labels between the intersections of each graph, not just one or the other.

Comment: The col_order works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the test data and the original test code give:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 5000, 200, 5, 900], ['tom', 7000, 500, 5, 900], ['nick', 7000, 300, 4, 4000], ['nick', 8000, 200, 4, 4000], ['juli', 9000, 300, 2, 8000, ], ['juli', 15000, 300, 2, 8000, ], ['TEST', 10000, 300, 3, 8000], ['TEST', 8000, 800, 3, 8000], ['hang', 5000, 330, 1.6, 5000], ['hang', 1000, 330, 5, 5000]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Donor', 'Days-post-ARV', 'CD4', 'VL', 'Days Post-COLDATE'])

# creating two separate datframes
merged1 = df
merged2 = df

# function for reference vertical line
def vertical_mean_line(x, **kwargs):
     plt.axvline(merged1[x].mean(), **kwargs)

# for the first dataframe
g = sns.relplot(data=merged1, x='Days-post-ARV', y='VL', col='Donor', col_wrap=3, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5,
                color='b')
# for the vertical line
g.map(vertical_mean_line, x='Days-post-ARV', ls="--", color='g')

# for the second dataframe
for patid, ax in g.axes_dict.items():  # axes_dict is new in seaborn 0.11.2
     ax1 = ax.twinx()
     sns.lineplot(data=merged2[merged2['Donor'] == patid], x='Days-post-ARV', y='CD4', color='r', ax=ax1)
     ax1.set_ylim(0, 1200)
g.add_legend()
g.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You'll notice the order of the subplots is the same as the order the donors appear in the dataframe: `['tom', 'nick', 'juli', 'TEST', 'hang']`.

[image: sns.relplot original]

It seems Seaborn not only removes the left y label, it also sets it invisible. You'll need to set it visible again.  Note that changes to `ax` influence the left ticks and left labels, while changes to `ax1` influence the ticks and the labels at the right of the subplots.

Changing the code to add a new `col_order`. And adding `ax.set_ylabel('VL', visible=True)`:

```py
# for the first dataframe, NEW col_order
g = sns.relplot(data=merged1, x='Days-post-ARV', y='VL', col='Donor', col_wrap=3, kind="line", height=4, aspect=1.5,
                color='b', col_order=['tom', 'juli', 'nick', 'TEST', 'hang'])
# for the vertical line
g.map(vertical_mean_line, x='Days-post-ARV', ls="--", color='g')

# for the second dataframe
for patid, ax in g.axes_dict.items():  # axes_dict is new in seaborn 0.11.2
     ax1 = ax.twinx()
     sns.lineplot(data=merged2[merged2['Donor'] == patid], x='Days-post-ARV', y='CD4', color='r', ax=ax1)
     ax1.set_ylim(0, 1200)
     ax.set_ylabel('VL', visible=True) # ADDED

g.add_legend()
g.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: new sns.relplot]

Comment: Love it, JohanC! Thanks so much. You are the best.